# Extracting a eia_608 stream from a mpeg2 transport stream with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, closed-captions

I'm trying to convert a MPEG2 Transport Stream to a MP4 stream. The video and audio are fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to tell ffmpeg to extract the eia_608 stream from the video and place it in a stream for the mp4 or mov. I've tried a straight copy as shown below.

```
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i tsfile3.ts  -codec:v copy -fflags genpts -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -codec:a copy -codec:s copy -f mov tsfile3a.mp4
```

Has anyone done this? If so, could you help with the syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured this out. Just be aware it appears to only work with mpegvideo and not h264. The syntax is as follows:

> ffmpeg -i Closedcaption_rollup.ts -f lavfi -i "movie=Closedcaption_rollup.ts[out+subcc]"  -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:1 -c:s mov_text test_out.mp4

This is using the ffmpeg fate test clip. 
The caveats are:

1. Appears to only work with mpegvideo. I can't get it to work with h264
2. Doesn't output eia_608 type in the file, it converts it to mov_text.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I looked at a lot of more recent posts than this all saying this couldn't be done. But this seems to work for me.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Examples-5
The last example seems to provide some documentation on this.